# Check if a Database is Empty (No Tables) in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How can I check if a database is empty in SQLAlchemy?

I know you can do `inspector.dialect.has_table(engine.connect(), 'table_name')` to check for the existence of a single table, but I want to know if there are any tables at all in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check tables in current database:

```
db.engine.table_names()
```

or after creating `engine` variable from connection string:

```
engine = sql.create_engine("connection_string")

sql.inspect(engine).get_table_names()
```

Comment: For the scenario I have mentioned, as you have said, `if db.engine.table_names()` seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @MinuraPunchihewa Good. mark the answer as accepted if your problem solved.